# How do you capture the SQL queries running in a CakePHP page?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.2

I have a production CakePHP site where I need to troubleshoot a slow SQL query. I want access to that great table CakePHP creates with the actual SQL query, execution time, etc, but I can't set the DEBUG level to 3 on a production site.

I imagine this is a simple but I just can't seem to figure out how I can get this information for a specific script and do something with it, like save it to a log file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/rainchen/2009/03/09/how-to-debug-as-in-rails) article will help you.

If you have access to MySQL configuration file you can log slow queries by [enabling log-slow-queries setting](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2007/01/22/enable-logging-of-slow-queries-slow-query-log-in-mysql-database/).

Comment: Good article. I wanted to avoid the slow query log, but oh well.

Answer (score 2):

For Cake 1.3 (not sure if this works in 1.2), have a look at `/cake/libs/view/elements/sql_dump.ctp` and adapt it to your needs:

```
$sources = ConnectionManager::sourceList();

foreach ($sources as $source) {
    $db =& ConnectionManager::getDataSource($source);
    if (!$db->isInterfaceSupported('getLog')) {
        continue;
    }

    $log = $db->getLog();

    // examine $log...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**DebugKit** is your friend.  There should be versions suitable for Cake 1.3, 2.x and 3.x.  It has a beautiful toolbar that displays all your SQL queries and the time taken to run each.

https://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit